# Python NumberGuess : console is stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have written the following code and when i launch the program in the prompt, it doesn't happen anything then. Why ?

Here is my code :

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

def get_user_guess() :
  guess = int(input("Guess the dice number: "))
  return guess

def roll_dice(number_of_sides):
  first_roll = randint (1, number_of_sides)
  second_roll = randint (1, number_of_sides)
  max_val = number_of_sides * 2
  print ("The maximum possible value is {:d}" .format(max_val))
  guess = get_user_guess()
  if guess > max_val:
    print ("result is invalid !")
roll_dice(6)
```

Comment: It doesn't happen anything? Any error message either? Are you sure?

Comment: The code you posted raises a NameError at line 15 ("if guess > max_val") but I assume you broke the indentation when posting the snippet here - please fix it btw. Else your code (kind of...) work for me, so the problem is mostly with how you run it. Plase post all the necessary informations to reproduce the issue if you hope to get some help.

Comment: yes ! nothing happens then

Comment: i have corrected the indentation but i don't get the NameError at line 15. I must add that i wrote this code in Python 2 on Codeacademy. When i enter the program name nothing happens then as is it should